# How to change an image associated with a web page when sharing link?

Tags: html, css, image

Whenever we share a link to this page: http://www.leadingpractice.com/our-people-and-values/our-leaders/, then we see an image of our former CEO. An old image that is supposedly somehow associated with that web page.

It looks like this (example of posting the link in a Skype chat): http://prntscr.com/hzvxot.

The image has been deleted from our server and is no longer available online. How can I change this image to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously it was NOT deleted or is still in (your/google/skype) cache. Funnily enough I know one of those guys ;) If I share this on Facebook, I get "von Rosen" first

Comment: for facebook use this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing and scrap the page again ... and as @mplungjan said, it's cache, so you need to wait for google and skype. And you have to use meta to say which image to use

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML of your page, you have a bunch of META tags.

The first image meta tag is this:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.leadingpractice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Mark-von-Rosing.png" />
```

Remove that meta tag and after Facebook updates their cache, another image will show up (whichever is the first image meta tag).

Comment: But this meta tag is actually correct. The image used in this tag is the one we want to use (i.e. http://www.leadingpractice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Mark-von-Rosing.png).

Comment: So, do we just wait until Skype/Facebook/Google/Whomever updates their caches up previously uploaded/used images?

Comment: Yes, in this case, you just wait. It can take up to a week. When did you change the meta tags/images?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to fix this issue. Great.

We are using Wordpress as our platform for the website, and I tried to set a "Featured Image" for the page itself. This might be what fixed it.

Thanks for the help, guys!